# ASP.Net MVC Read from multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, api, quartz.net

I would really appreciate some advice with this upcoming problem I need to resolve.

I have 2 separate business systems (let's call them System A and System B), both developed in Asp.Net MVC 5 and Entity Framework 5. Both systems use separate MS SQL Server databases. Both systems are hosted on the same web server.

There has never been any link between the systems in the past, however, I now need to make some of the data stored in System A available in System B.

For example, System A has a database table like this:

**tblCourse** --> Id, courseName, courseDate

And I now need to make the data in this table available to System B users. When I  say make available to System B users, I mean this information needs to also be stored in a table in System B's database.

At the moment I'm unsure how to do this as I've never had to extract data from multiple databases for one web application.

I need to research this further, but at the moment I'm thinking these might be possible options to use:

1. Create a 2nd database connection string within my web.config for System B which will point to the database of System A. Then use that connection to pull the data from the required table in System A into System B. I'm not sure if this is even possible or how this would integrate with my Entity Framework model which would already be based on my database for System B.

   2. Create a scheduled task (stored procs) with Quartz.Net to run every night to read the data from the required table in System A and insert into System B.
   3. Create an API inside the solution for System A that would provide the info System B needs, read it and insert the data into the database for System B. I've never created an API before and unsure if this would be suitable for this problem.

Any advice really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you need the data also in System's B database? Which system is responsible for adding/updating the data? It might be better if you keep the data in 1 system (for example System A) and expose an API to be consumed by other systems that need the data. Although there are some cases where for performance reasons it might be worth to have it replicated but keeping the data in sync makes it more complex

Comment: If you are not doing relationships (just fetching data), then just setup another context into that database. If you need relationships, you could create a SQL view in B that pulls from A.